# Find next command in nano?

Tags: linux, command-line, nano

I use `CTRL+W` then `Enter` every time, is there a "Find Next" command in nano?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can get a list of all keyboard shortcuts by pressing *^G* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>).

From *Main nano help text*:

```
M-W     (F16)           Repeat last search
```

*M-W* is Vim/Emacs notation, where *M* means <kbd>Meta</kbd> (a key present on MIT and Sun keyboards).

On IBM-compatible keyboards – depending on, e.g.,  your window manager and terminal emulator – you can invoke the shortcut with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (hold, tap), <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> (hold, tap) or <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd> (tap, tap).

<kbd>F16</kbd> can be emulated with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> (hold, tap); in general, <kbd>F<12+n></kbd> can be emulated with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F<n></kbd>. In the unlikely case your keyboard has such a key, you can simply press <kbd>F16</kbd>.

Comment: I actually read the help text, but didn't know `M` meant `ALT`. What does `M` mean BTW?

Comment: From Putty (Windows) ssh-ing to an Ubuntu, with `Configuration | Connection | Data | Terminal details | Terminal-type string` set to `linux` I confirm that the combination `Alt` + `M` works as "find next".

Comment: Short answer: `Alt + W`

Comment: Thanks! Only `Esc + W` worked for me, on xTerm.